# What are some high-profile websites that use OpenLayers and PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2

I think there are many convincing arguments for using PostGIS but I am interested in showing people examples of websites that use PostGIS and OpenLayers.

Some examples that I have seen are:

- [foursquare](https://foursquare.com/about/)
- [CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/)
- [Vizzuality](http://vizzuality.com/) (many examples)
- [WalkScore](http://www.walkscore.com/) (as far as I can tell)

Are there other examples that show good examples of this combination? I'm not sure if any of the sites that I listed are using OpenLayers as a central part of their functionality but I believe that they all use PostGIS.

Answer (score 6):

According to the following case study, the *Institut Géographique National* of France chose PostGIS over proprietary alternatives like Oracle or IBM's DB2.

Case study: http://postgis.net/2012/10/18/ign

Answer (score 3):

Many OpenStreetMap sites are using PostGIS as the backend layer - for instance openstreetmap.org (at least as far as I know), they also use OpenLayers to show the tiles on osm.org...

Answer (score 3):

At the moment I am developing a [maps.geodan.nl](http://maps.geodan.nl) using PostGIS and Openlayers.

Answer (score 2):

We [developed a solution](http://www.scotland.gov.uk/Topics/marine/seamanagement/nmpihome/nmpi) for our client that they have embedded into their website using an iFrame.

All of the data is stored in PostGIS (with the exception of OpenStreetMap) and rendered to the client using WMS. On the server we are using GeoServer and the client is OpenLayers.